# How do I compile in Java with a batch file?

Tags: java

Alright, I am an extreme newb when it comes to coding and I am trying to compile a rsps (private server) just as a start. It comes with a batch file that would usually work, but I think I had to upgrade the java version and directory. So I did. Then when I tried to run it, cmd popped up and gave the error " -d is not a recognized option".

Here is the batch code....

```
@echo off
title Compiler
echo Fixed Compiler By mb
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\java" -d <bin> -cp lib/mysql.jar;lib/netty-3.2.jar;lib/xstream.jar;lib/xpp.jar;xpp3-1.1.4c.jar -sourcepath src src/org/dementhium/RS2Server.java
pause
```

The original code didnt have the <> around bin. Now that I added those, the cmd prompt says `"acess is denied... press any key to continue"`. I know some of you guys might laugh, but I barely know what I am doing.

Comment: `<` and `>` are redirection operators in command files. Your command line is basically saying 'run C:\Program...\Java.exe -d', accepting input (`<`) from `bin`, and send the output (`>`) to `-cp something`, which is obviously not what you want. In other words, adding the `<>` is NOT what you want to do - it's probably what's causing the `access denied` error.

Comment: @KenWhite: if you read the question closely, it says: *"The original code didnt have the <> around bin"*

Comment: @m0skit0, and if *you* read the question carefully, at that point the original error was about an invalid commandline switch. When the `<>` was added, the error message changed to `access denied'. :)

Comment: So? If *you* read my answer, you'll see that the invalid commandline switch is because he's not using the correct executable. His second attempt is useless and has nothing to do with his problem, actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java compiler is *javac*, not *java*.

Comment: No problem, please mark as correct answer if that worked for you, and welcome to StackOverflow ;)